# PROCEDURE addWorkFlowLog already exists

Tags: sql

I have used " SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE addWorkFlowLog" in navicat and it show "PROCEDURE addWorkFlowLog does not exist", then I use "CREATE PROCEDURE addWorkFlowLog..." sql but it show "PROCEDURE addWorkFlowLog already exists" !!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG8hx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Zry.png)

I want to create Procedure in mysql, but it cann't work, I want your help